# How to select a list of edges to draw in networkx.draw

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, networkx

I have a networkx graph with many edges and for this reason I want to select a subset that I want to draw. But there is strange behaviour.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(0,1,color=.1,weight=2)
G.add_edge(1,2,color=.4,weight=4)
G.add_edge(2,3,color=1.4,weight=6)
G.add_edge(3,4,color=2.4,weight=3)
G.add_edge(4,0,color=5.7,weight=1)

colors = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'color').values()
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight').values()

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

# This works:
nx.draw(G, pos, 
        edge_color=colors, 
        width=list(weights),
        with_labels=True,
        node_color='lightgreen',
       )
# This works too:
nx.draw(G, pos, 
        edge_color=colors, 
        width=list(weights),
        with_labels=True,
        node_color='lightgreen',
        edgelist=[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,0)],
       )
```

This is the result. (I will add a colorbar later, so the colors can be interpreted).

[image: Image that is drawn]

```
# This however gives an error:
# ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0.1
nx.draw(G, pos, 
        edge_color=colors, 
        width=list(weights),
        with_labels=True,
        node_color='lightgreen',
        edgelist=[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),],
       )
```

Is there a way to prevent this error? It seems to me that this is bug. But maybe there is something that I miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `colors = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'color').values()`

This gives `dict_values([0.1, 5.7, 0.4, 1.4, 2.4])`

`draw` is trying to match 5 values to only 3 edges

So like you said, you have to resize the `colors` dict

Comment: Do you have any ideas, why this error was a value error?

Comment: The error I get is `ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 0.1`.  In the `matplotlib` documentation https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/_modules/matplotlib/colors.html it mentions `The module also provides functions for checking whether an object can be
interpreted as a color (`is_color_like`), for converting such an object
to an RGBA tuple (`to_rgba`) or to an HTML-like hex string in the
"#rrggbb" format (`to_hex`), and a sequence of colors to an (n, 4)
RGBA array (`to_rgba_array`).  Caching is used for efficiency.`, so the object can't be interpreted as an RGBA value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error: You also have to edit the color-key-word-argument:

```
edgelist=[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),]
nx.draw(G, pos, 
        edge_color=[G.edges[e]['color'] for e in edgelist], 
        width=list(weights),
        with_labels=True,
        node_color='lightgreen',
        edgelist=edgelist,
       )
```

But I still think that the error that I got was not helpful...